# Бот написанный на discord.api пишет в чат только одно сообщение

Tags: python, discord-api, discord.py

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'не скажу'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def say(ctx, arg): 
    await ctx.send(arg) 

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Попробуйте заменить в функции `say` аргумент `arg` на `*args`, и `*args` отправлять обратно. Либо отправляйте аргумент функции боту в кавычках: `!say "починись, починись, пожалуйста"`

Comment: ничего не изменилось, с * вообще ошибку выдёт. Ну блин, ставить каждый раз кавычки, это не красиво

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def say(ctx, *arg): 
    await ctx.send(' '.join(arg)) 

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]